# Login into Gatsby, with Apollo using JWT in Drupal Backend

Tags: jwt, drupal-8, apollo, react-apollo, gatsby

I have created a Gatsby site, using Apollo, and I am using Drupal 8 as backend. I have a login form, and I am using mutation to login a user, basically get a token (JWT) from Drupal 8. so that I can include it in my further request. But issue is that I am not able to get the token.

Drupal URL: http://localhost:8200
Gatsby URL: http://localhost:8000

const httpLink = createHttpLink({
  uri: 'http://localhost:8200'
})

const client = new ApolloClient({
  link: httpLink,
  cache: new InMemoryCache(),
})

const LOGIN_MUTATION = gql
  `mutation LoginMutation($email: String!, $password: String!) {
    login(email: $email, password: $password) {
      token
    }
  }`

const { username, password} = this.state

```
<Mutation mutation={LOGIN_MUTATION} variables={{username, password}} onCompleted={data => this._confirm(data)} >
            {mutation => (
              <Button variant="contained" color="primary" size="small" onClick={mutation} >
                Sign-In
              </Button>
            )}
          </Mutation>
```

Any help would be appreciated.